# Could not initialize proxy - no Session session.LOAD and EVICT

Tags: nhibernate, session

i got problem with load and evict in session of hibernate here are the codes.

```
        public virtual void ClearData(T obj)
    {

        using (ISession ses = SessionManager.OpenSession())
        {
            ses.Evict(obj);
        }

    }

        public virtual T Load<T>(object id)
    {
        using (ISession ses = SessionManager.OpenSession())
        {
            return (T)ses.Load(typeof(T), id);
        }
    }
```

calling it with

```
            Firmy fir = new Firmy();
        fir.ClearData(fir);
        var yol = fir.Load<Firmy>(6);
        Response.Write("<br/><br/><br/> TEST get");
        Response.Write(yol.NazwaFirmy);
        Response.Write("<br/><br/><br/> TEST EVI");
        fir.ClearData(yol);
        Response.Write(yol.NazwaFirmy);
```

and here is session menager

```
    public  class SessionManager
{
    #region Class Member Declarations
    private static readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private static readonly Configuration _configuration;
    #endregion
    static SessionManager()
    {
        _configuration = new Configuration();
        _configuration.Configure();
        _configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(SessionManager).Assembly);
        _sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }


    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
    #region Class Property Declarations

    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get { return _sessionFactory; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I wanna to load some data of fir with load function and then clear data with cleardata but idk how to do this was based on some tutroial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you exaclty get the error?

A couple of things that are not ok:

- You're calling evict (first time) for an object that is not related to any nhibernate session (you just created it). Evict is for detaching an object from a session, but only make sense if you loaded the object with that session.
- You create a session on every opearation and that's not the recommended way to go. You load an object with one session and then you try to evict it on a different session and that's not possible.

Comment: Hmm can u tell me how to change my session menager to prevent thouse situacions?
And the error is always on call evict or load.

Comment: You'd need to change the method to get the session. You'd create a new one only if there is none already created. You'll also need a method to close the session. I recomend you to use the session manager from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13390/NHibernate-Best-Practices-with-ASP-NET-1-2nd-Ed)

Comment: Or could you help me to write one on my example?

Comment: The article on code project is really good. I strongly recommend you to take a look. It was a reference for me in my early ages of learning nhibernate.